# Program 'coverlet.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt D:\a\1\s\pipeline.ps1:15 char:1

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to run a shell script in azure devOps build pipeline to publish test result code coverage into coverage tab in azure pipeline and I get this error. Here is my script

```
"install tools:"
&dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path . --version 4.0.12
&dotnet tool install coverlet.console --tool-path . --version 1.4.1

"`nmake reports dir:"
mkdir .\reports

"`nrun tests:"
$unitTestFile = gci -Recurse | ?{ $_.FullName -like "**\*Test*.dll" }
Write-Host "`$unitTestFile value: $unitTestFile"

$coverlet = "$pwd\coverlet.exe"

"calling $coverlet for $($unitTestFile.FullName)"
&$coverlet $unitTestFile.FullName --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest $($unitTestFile.FullName) --logger:trx" --format "cobertura"

"`ngenerate report(s)"
gci -Recurse | 
    ?{ $_.Name -eq "coverage.cobertura.xml" } | 
    %{ &"$pwd\reportgenerator.exe" "-reports:$($_.FullName)" "-targetdir:reports" "-reporttypes:HTMLInline;HTMLChart" }
```

**Update - Error Log**

```
D:\a\1\s\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.15.1\build\netcoreapp2.0\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll
Program 'coverlet.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too longAt D:\a\1\s\pipeline.ps1:15 char:1
+ &$coverlet $unitTestFile.Name --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At D:\a\1\s\pipeline.ps1:15 char:72
+ ... e --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest $($unitTestFile.Name) --logg ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFaile
```

d

Comment: Could you proof which `*.dll` cause the error? `$unitTestFile.FullName` could also a problem when it contains spaces. May replace with `"$($unitTestFile.FullName)"`?

Comment: @MarTin I have updated the question with the error log.

Comment: That not the solution of your problem, but dosen't make it sense for you to filter this assembly (`NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll`)? You don't realy want to measure the coverage of the **NUnit3** Framework or? Sadly your rule `"**\*Test*.dll"` include this file.

Comment: Even I do change the wildcard error is there. So that I don't think that is related to dll

Comment: Could you add the `--verbosity detailed` paramter to you `coverlet` call? Is there something related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this argument `$unitTestFile = gci -Recurse | ?{ $_.FullName -like "**\*Test*.dll" }` takes more than 1 dll file and had to reduced that to single dll. That resolved the problem.

Comment: How could you do it if you had more than one dll file to check?